# Rotating Vertex Array Object not working

Tags: c++, arrays, opengl, graphics, graphics2d

I am using vertex arrays to store circle vertices and colors.

Here is the setup function:

```
void setup1(void) 
{
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);

    // Enable two vertex arrays: co-ordinates and color.
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    // Specify locations for the co-ordinates and color arrays.
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, Vertices1);
    glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, Colors1);
}
```

The global declaration of the arrays is here:

```
static float Vertices1[500] = { 0 };
static float Colors1[500] = { 0 };
```

The arrays are all set up here (R is the radius, X and Y are the (X,Y) center, and t is the angle parameter of the circle)

```
void doGlobals1()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numVertices1 * 3; i += 3)
    {
        Vertices1[i] = X + R * cos(t);
        Vertices1[i + 1] = Y + R * sin(t);
        Vertices1[i + 2] = 0.0;
        t += 2 * PI / numVertices1;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < numVertices1 * 3; j += 3)
    {
        Colors1[j] = (float)rand() / (float)RAND_MAX;
        Colors1[j + 1] = (float)rand() / (float)RAND_MAX;
        Colors1[j + 2] = (float)rand() / (float)RAND_MAX;
    }
}
```

Finally, this is where the shape is drawn.

```
// Window 1 drawing routine.
void drawScene1(void)
{  
    glutSetWindow(win1);
    glLoadIdentity();

    doGlobals1();
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glRotatef(15, 1, 0, 0);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, numVertices1);

    glFlush();
}
```

Without the Rotation, the circle draws just fine. The circle also draws fine with any Scale/Translate function. I suspect there is some special protocol necessary to rotate an object drawn with vertex arrays.

Can anyone tell me where I have gone wrong, what I will need to do in order to rotate the object, or offer any advice?

Comment: So when you include the rotation, suddenly you can't see the picture anymore?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly it.

Also (perhaps unrelated to the problem in general) when I scale the circle it gets translated in the direction it scales (e.g. Scaling X by 1.5 also translates it in the X direction).

Comment: Try moving to your Modelview matrix. I have worked with OpenTK mainly so I don't know the code for C++ but before you load your identity matrix, do something like this `glMatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview)`

Comment: Thanks for your help! It ended up being a very trivial error (see marked answer) but I appreciate your input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
glRotatef(15, 1, 0, 0);
              ^ why the X axis?
```

The default ortho projection matrix has pretty tight near/far clipping planes: -1 to 1.

Rotating your circle of X/Y coordinates outside of the X/Y plane will tend to make those points get clipped.

Rotate around the Z axis instead:

```
glRotatef(15, 0, 0, 1);
```

Comment: This was the solution. Much more simple than I would have liked to admit.

I still have the problem that when I scale, the object translates on the axis I scaled (e.g. scaling by 1.5, 1.0, 1.0 translates the object in the +X direction). Any advice on this would be appreciated!

Comment: Remove the X/Y offsets when you generate the circle so it's centered on (0,0).

Comment: You are very right. I thought that the coordinates of the object only mattered during a rotation, I did not know it mattered during a scale as well. Thanks for your help!